How to manage operations in a programming language
I am trying to write my own programming language in kotlin, but I am having trouble with operators. Currently, I am manually writing code to handle each situation, but this seems inefficient
This is the code to handle addition, it seems to work in most cases, but it is stupidly big for just an operator
// inside the lexer
val additionPattern = Regex("""(\w+)\s*=\s*((?:"[^"]*"|\d+|\w+)(?:\s*\+\s*(?:"[^"]*"|\d+|\w+))*)""")

additionPattern.matchEntire(code)?.let {
        val varName = it.groups[1]!!.value
        val parts = it.groups[2]!!.value.split("+").map { it.trim() }
        return listOf("multi_addition", varName) + parts
    }
// inside the interpreter function
"multi_addition" -> {
            val varName = tokens[1]
            val parts = tokens.drop(2)
            if (parts[0].startsWith("\"")) {
                var result = parts[0].removeSurrounding("\"")
                var sum = 0
                var addingNumbers = false

                for (part in parts.drop(1)) {
                    when {
                        part.toDoubleOrNull() != null -> {
                            if (!addingNumbers) {
                                addingNumbers = true
                                sum = part.toInt()
                            } else {
                                sum += part.toInt()
                            }
                        }
                        variables.containsKey(part) -> {
                            when (val value = variables[part]) {
                                is InterpreterValue.NumberValue -> {
                                    if (!addingNumbers) {
                                        addingNumbers = true
                                        sum = value.value.toInt()
                                    } else {
                                        sum += value.value.toInt()
                                    }
                                }
                                is InterpreterValue.StringValue -> {
                                    if (addingNumbers) {
                                        result += sum.toString()
                                        addingNumbers = false
                                        sum = 0
                                    }
                                    result += value.value
                                }
                                else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid token in addition: '$part'")
                            }
                        }
                        part.startsWith("\"") -> {
                            if (addingNumbers) {
                                result += sum.toString()
                                addingNumbers = false
                                sum = 0
                            }
                            result += part.removeSurrounding("\"")
                        }
                        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid token in addition: '$part'")
                    }
                }

                if (addingNumbers) {
                    result += sum.toString()
                }

                variables[varName] = InterpreterValue.StringValue(result)
            } else {
                var sum = 0.0
                for (part in parts) {
                    when {
                        part.toDoubleOrNull() != null -> sum += part.toDouble()
                        variables.containsKey(part) -> {
                            when (val value = variables[part]) {
                                is InterpreterValue.NumberValue -> sum += value.value
                                else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid token in numeric addition: '$part'")
                            }
                        }
                        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid token in numeric addition: '$part'")
                    }
                }
                variables[varName] = InterpreterValue.NumberValue(sum)
            }
        }

and all this just to make addition work. Is there a better way to handle operators? Like a way which can perform PEMDAS on integers and handle string-integer cases, for example, cases such as var1 = "The sum is: " + someIntegerVariable - (5 + 10) / 5 * 20 + " !" Where there are integers and string, and you have to perform PEMDAS. Handling a case like this in the way I am currently doing will result in a stupidly big function. Any help is appreciated.

Regular expressions are not sufficient to parse an arbitrary expression. You need a parser for that instead, also see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram -- You need to define the grammar first (possibly in BNF form, see link), then you need to scan the expression into tokens and parse the tokens to create a syntax tree. If you have any specific question about the, please [edit] your question accordingly.

This seems the question about designing a compiler and not about Kotlin. Please tag it appropriately.

It took me way too long to realize that what I need was a parser that will convert my tokens to a syntax tree, that will be then passed to the interpreter to be interpreted. But thanks for the help, it will be useful for designing the parser!
